# php function saves data only when visitor is rating, when user is logged it doesn't - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using gd star rating plugin for wordpress, it uses this function to save thumbs data:

```
    function add_vote_comment_thumb($id, $user, $ip, $ua, $vote) {
        global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
        $trend_date = date("Y-m-d");
        $sql_trend = sprintf("SELECT count(*) FROM %sgdsr_votes_trend WHERE vote_date = '%s' and vote_type = 'cmmthumb' and id = %s", $table_prefix, $trend_date, $id);
        $trend_data = $wpdb->get_var($sql_trend);

        $trend_added = false;
        if ($trend_data == 0) {
            $trend_added = true;
            if ($user > 0) {
                $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %sgdsr_votes_trend (id, vote_type, user_voters, user_votes, vote_date) VALUES (%s, 'cmmthumb', 1, %s, '%s')",
                    $table_prefix, $id, $vote, $trend_date);
                $wpdb->query($sql);
            } else {
                $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %sgdsr_votes_trend (id, vote_type, visitor_voters, visitor_votes, vote_date) VALUES (%s, 'cmmthumb', 1, %s, '%s')",
                    $table_prefix, $id, $vote, $trend_date);
                $wpdb->query($sql);
            }
        }

        if ($user > 0) {
            $part = $vote == 1 ? "user_recc_plus = user_recc_plus + 1" : "user_recc_minus = user_recc_minus + 1";

            if (!$trend_added) {
                $sql = sprintf("UPDATE %sgdsr_votes_trend SET user_voters = user_voters + 1, user_votes = user_votes + %s WHERE id = %s and vote_type = 'cmmthumb' and vote_date = '%s'",
                    $table_prefix, $vote, $id, $trend_date);
                $wpdb->query($sql);
            }
        } else {
            $part = $vote == 1 ? "visitor_recc_plus = visitor_recc_plus + 1" : "visitor_recc_minus = visitor_recc_minus + 1";

            if (!$trend_added) {
                $sql = sprintf("UPDATE %sgdsr_votes_trend SET visitor_voters = visitor_voters + 1, visitor_votes = visitor_votes + %s WHERE id = %s and vote_type = 'cmmthumb' and vote_date = '%s'",
                    $table_prefix, $vote, $id, $trend_date);
                $wpdb->query($sql);
            }
        }

        $sql = sprintf("UPDATE %sgdsr_data_comment SET %s, last_voted_recc = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE comment_id = %s",
            $table_prefix, $part, $id);
        $wpdb->query($sql);

wp_gdsr_dump("SAVE_THUMB_VOTE", $sql);

        $logsql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %sgdsr_votes_log (id, vote_type, user_id, vote, object, voted, ip, user_agent) VALUES (%s, 'cmmthumb', %s, %s, '', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
            $table_prefix, $id, $user, $vote, str_replace("'", "''", current_time('mysql')), $ip, $ua);
        $wpdb->query($logsql);

wp_gdsr_dump("SAVE_THUMB_LOG", $logsql);

    }
```

I want this data to be also saved in comments karma field present in wordpress db. So at the end of the function I add:

```
//Integrate with comment karma system
    $up_qry = sprintf("SELECT visitor_recc_plus FROM %sgdsr_data_comment WHERE comment_id = %s", $table_prefix, $id);
    $votes_up = $wpdb->get_var($up_qry);
    $down_qry = sprintf("SELECT visitor_recc_minus FROM %sgdsr_data_comment WHERE comment_id = %s", $table_prefix, $id);
    $votes_down = $wpdb->get_var($down_qry);
    $votes = $votes_up - $votes_down;
    $votes_qry = sprintf("UPDATE %scomments SET comment_karma = $votes WHERE comment_ID = %s", $table_prefix, $id);
    $wpdb->query($votes_qry);
```

But this only saves data to comment_karma when visitor is rating, when I'm logged in as user it doesn't save data to corresponding column!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the code you are adding simply ignores votes from non-visitors.  Look at it in the context of the larger code snippet.  That first snippets makes the following changes:

- **Logged in user votes up:** increment `user_recc_plus`
- **Logged in user votes down:** increment `user_recc_minus`
- **Visitor votes up:** increment `visitor_recc_plus`
- **Visitor votes down:** increment `visitor_recc_minus`

Your second snippet seems to ignore the source of the vote.  It sets the karma value according to `visitor_recc_plus - visitor_recc_minus` only.

I don't have enough context to give you a definite fix, but couldn't you simply update the karma with the relative change ($vote rather than $votes)?  If so, all you need is this:

```
    $votes_qry = sprintf("UPDATE %scomments SET comment_karma = comment_karma + $vote WHERE comment_ID = %s", $table_prefix, $id);
    $wpdb->query($votes_qry);
```

Comment: I figured it out, simply duplicated snippet and replaced values with user_recc_plus all inside conditional which checks if visitor is user or not.